# Не отображаеться блок при изминении translateY

Tags: html, css, transform

Сверстал блок который после написания скрипта будет выезжать при нажатии иконки меню. Пытаюсь его открыть путём изменения translateY() с -100% на 0 но он не отображается. В чём может быть проблема?

https://tekeo-ronin.github.io/skinali-factory/

Comment: скажите имя класса или id этого блока

Comment: `.navbar .menu` ?

Comment: почему у вас такая последовательность `.navbar .menu`? `.navbar` и `.menu` на одном уровне у вас.

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/186999) - **НЕТ**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Последовательность `.navbar .menu` в вашем css не правильная. Элементы на одном уровне. Замените свои `.navbar .menu` и `.navbar .menu_active` на этот код. А дальше пишите скрипт, присваивая классу `.menu` класс `.menu_active`.

```
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 0;
  background-color: #507fe1;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.menu_active {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Изменил последовательность и всё заработало. Затупил не заметил)

Comment: рад был помочь. Если возникнут проблемы с логикой отображения меню, то обращайтесь. Напишу.